# Точки по краям текста

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно подобное реализовать?

Comment: можно через псевдоэлементы before & after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы использовал `::before` & `::after`, оформленные в виде точек и размещенные по краям через `position: absolute`.

```css
.dotted{
    color: blue;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
.dotted::after, .dotted::before{
    content: "●";
    position: absolute;
}
.dotted::before{
    left: 0; 
}
.dotted::after{
    right: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="dotted">История</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант  можно через мнемонику в HTML`&bull`

```
<p>&bull;История &bull;</p>
```